# Requirements for Reaper DAW

Tags: 22.10, daw

I want to install Reaper on Ubuntu 22.10. The requirements for linux are as follows:

- libc6, libstdc++ for gcc 4.x or later
- libgdk-3 (you can also target headless or libgdk-2 if you build your own libSwell from WDL)
- ALSA

I want to know if Ubuntu 22.10 already comes with these packages installed or not. If not, how do I install them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ubuntu versions **do not** come with the compiler tools installed for C and C++ and such.  That's because it's not a small request to get all the build libraries installed - it takes up a not insignificant portion of space on disk.

---

To get the GCC and standard libs, that's a single task - in command line run:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This installs GCC, G++, all the standard C libs, etc.

---

GDK is actually part of the GTK libraries - it's a low level library but it's part of the GTK libraries.  You install libgdk with this:

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

---

Now, ALSA may be harder to get working.  I'm not 100% fluent in the ALSA libraries, but in theory running `sudo apt install libasound2-dev` *should* get you the ALSA libraries you need.

---

Once you're done, follow whatever README instructions exist for compiling the software you want to compile.